# Automatically apply parent label to sublabel in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

When labeling a message with a nested label the message does not appear in the parent label, which in my opinion would be the power having a label hierarchy.

Is there a way to automatically apply the parent label when moving a message to a sublabel?

For example, given the following labels...

```
Pending
    Today
    Week
```

I would like every message labeled *Today* to also appear in *Pending*, without having to apply a filter manually.

Comment: you have to use a filter

Comment: Check my answer if you dont want to manually create all parent label filters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve a similar functionality this by enabling the Quick Links lab and then setting a quick link to the following seach:

```
label:pending OR label:pending-today OR label:pending-week
```

Comment: I am trying to access my mail via IMAP. Quick Links doesn't show up as an IMAP folder, does it?

Answer (score 2):

I've achieved this by creating a new filter with all child labels linked with OR and (edited to clarify) applying parent label to it, i.e.:

`label:parent-child1 OR label:parent-child2` and so on...

No Quick Links thingy (found that solution also in some other sites) and so far everything works as expected.

Comment: GMail says: Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g. "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming mail.

Comment: @badc0de: Does this still work for you? I get the same warning that the filter "will never match incoming mail".

Answer (score 1):

For me the best solution is to make two identical filters, one for each label:

- One that applies the parent label
- Another that applies the nested label

Answer (score 0):

When you are dragging emails from inbox which are already labeled as the parent label (I automatically label it with a filter), try selecting that specific email (having a tick box checked), then drag the email to nested label. By doing this it will apply both labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit of editing:

1. Go to settings → Filters and blocked address
2. Check all the filters that apply the sublabels
3. Export the filters
4. Edit the XML and replace all the `<parent>/<sublabel>` labels to `<parent>`, then save the file
5. Go to setting → Filters and blocker address → import new filters
6. Import the edited files

Voila, you have duplicated all the sublabel filters to parent label filters.